# What's wrong with that SQL syntax?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I'm told to make some changes to the schema of our database, so I wrote the following script that does the following:

1. Update the value of the table, according the the value of another table
2. Delete the column that contains the id pointing to the other table

The entire script should only be executed if the id_to_other_table exists of course

Here is my SQL

```
IF EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'title_id' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'
)
BEGIN   
    UPDATE
        my_table
    SET
        my_table.title = other_table.value
        FROM
        my_table
        INNER JOIN
        other_table
    ON
        my_table.title_id = other_table.id
    WHERE other_table.language_id = 1 --hardcoded

    ALTER TABLE my_table
    DROP COLUMN title_id
END
```

The first time I run this SQL, the code is executed properly. When I run it once more, instead of doing nothing, it gives me the following error, pointing to the line after the `ON` part of the `JOIN`:

`Invalid column name 'my_table.title_id'`

If I replace the contents of the `BEGIN` - `END` block with `print "Does the column exists?"` it correctly displays nothing, so the `BEGIN` - `END` block is ending preemptively for some reason...

Any ideas?

Comment: how can you join on `title_id` after dropping it?

Comment: It's not supposed to join it if it's not there, yet it tried. That was the point of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the error is generated because you are executing multiple sql statements inside the block (a batch). As soon as you have a batch, some rules apply. Since you are ALTERING and referencing the same table inside 1 batch, the compile error occurs.
As soon as you seperate the both sql statements, you won't get a compile error:

```
    IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'title_id' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'
    )
    BEGIN   
        UPDATE
            my_table
        SET
            my_table.title = other_table.value
            FROM
            my_table
            INNER JOIN
            other_table
        ON
           my_table.title_id = other_table.id
        WHERE other_table.language_id = 1 --hardcoded

        END

    IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'title_id' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'
    )
    BEGIN   
        ALTER TABLE my_table
        DROP COLUMN title_id
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL is parsed as a whole, before execution. So despite the conditional statements not being run, they're still checked for validity.  You could encapsulate the commands as strings and use `exec` or `sp_executesql` to run them, as a workaround.